# How to add class selected in select form php

Tags: php, explode, implode

i want to add `class="selected"` to `option` in my select form.

for example in `$tags['tags_name']` i have data from database like this.

```
tags_name
-----------
English
Japanese
Korean
Mandarin
Indonesian
```

for example in my posting im already selected **English, Japanese and Indonesian** and insert it to database. then i call it with `$data['tags_name']`.

so in my select form i want to add `class="selected"` for every `tags_name` i have in posting.

this is select form should like.

```
<select multiple class="selectpicker" id="tags[]" name="tags[]" form="edit_post">
<option class="selected">English</option>
<option class="selected">Japanese</option>
<option>Korean</option>
<option>Mandarin</option>
<option class="selected">Indonesian</option>
</select>
```

cause in my database posting i have **English, Japanese and Indonesian** so in their option `class="selected"` added.

here what i try

```
<select multiple class="selectpicker" id="tags[]" name="tags[]" form="edit_post">
<?php foreach ($datatag as $tags): ?>
<option <?php if (isset($data['tags_name'] == $tags['tags_name'])): ?>
    <?php echo 'class="selected"'; ?>
<?php endif ?>><?php echo $tags['tags_name'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if (isset($data['hardsub'] == $tags['tags_name']))
```

with:

```
if ($data['hardsub'] == $tags['tags_name'])  // no `isset` here
```

In case of `$data` being an array, you need `in_array` or similar approach.

`strpos` example:

```
if (strpos($data['hardsub'], $tags['tags_name']) !== false)
```

Comment: not working, why? cause in `$data['hardsub']` its print `English, Japanese and Indonesian` but in `$tags['tags_name']` that print one by one language, so in manual **English, Japanese and Indonesian** not same with **English**

Comment: Then use `strpos`. Or exploding by `,` and  `and` to get array of values.

Comment: yup, i know must using strpost or explode, but i dont know how to use it. haha

Comment: Added a `strpos` example. For more information - refer to php manual.